# How to filter based on a range of dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

for instance I want to filter (or format) all dates between 09.02.2002. and 05.04.2002.
keep in mind that I am using european format.
The problem arises from the fact that excel doesn't recognize that 09.02.2002. comes before 05.04.2002. and is therefor less than the latter because it recognizes a "9" being larger than "5" and Im having a lot of dates which are way out of my intended range being filtered.

Comment: A clear vote for ISO 8601 from me. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your source data to date format.

The formula in cell D2 in the image below is:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(C2,4),MID(C2,4,2),LEFT(C2,2))
```

This function will work in the same way regardless of your region. When applied in your region, your values in D2:D3 will be:

```
5/4/2002
9/2/2002
```

[image]